# Use JSON file as value when inserting to MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a bunch of JSON files (say a.json, b.json, c.json). I know I can import each of them into a MongoDB collection using

```
mongoimport -d db -c collection --file x.json --jsonArray
```

And my collection will contain the three jsons. But I'd like to have the jsons be the values to keys which identify them. That is, instead of having my collection contain the following:

```
a.json, b.json, c.json
```

I'd like:

```
{ "a" : a.json }, { "b" : b.json }, { "c" : c.json }
```

Is there some functionality in Mongo's insert() method like: 
    db.collection.insert( { "a" : a.json } ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to merge your 3 files with the required format and then import it with `mongoimport` :

```
jq -s '{"a":.[0],"b":.[1],"c":.[2] }' a.json b.json c.json
```

Btw, it will work even if your json files have different root element (json object or array). The result will be like :

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "field": "2"
    },
    {
      "field": "5"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "field": "2"
    },
    {
      "field": "1"
    }
  ],
  "c": [
    {
      "field": "3"
    },
    {
      "field": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can store this into a new json file and then import it into mongoDB :

```
jq -s '{"a":.[0],"b":.[1],"c":.[2] }' a.json b.json c.json > input.json

mongoimport -d db -c testDB --file input.json
```

The result would be :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b2fa56fa97671e9876afa8"), "a" : [ { "field" : "2" }, { "field" : "5" } ], "b" : [ { "field" : "2" }, { "field" : "1" } ], "c" : [ { "field" : "3" }, { "field" : "2" } ] }
```